# Design issue in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display multiple li's under a ul. But by using the below code I am getting gap above the first li.

[image]

Screen shot: The gap I mentioned is shown in red colour. I want to remove it. Can anybody solve it?
[image]

Comment: Probally the padding-top: 5px. Need the html to be sure!

Comment: Post the complete HTML and CSS

Comment: I used Padding top to display the Text If i remove it then all the text will only move to up not the li

Comment: Ok but can you post the HTML and CSS. Maybe a fiddle will be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the red background is showing, it's a padding on the submenu list.

Try adding:

```
#nav li.off ul li:hover ul,
#nav li.on ul li:hover ul {
  padding-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: I have one more issue. as shown in screen shot if i mouse over on My profile tab the subsites under it also displaying under MyHomePage tab in IE7. In IE8 it is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

remove the `padding-top` and/or the `margin-top` of the `<ul>`

like this:

```
ul {
   padding-top: 0;
   margin-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: I used Padding top to display the Text If i remove it then all the text will only move to up not the li